# Bootstrap Image Responsive not working in Chorme and Cedot Browser

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

My Bootstrap 4 connection is working in Mozilla FireFox. But Not working in Chrome and Chedot Browser. My code is given bellow.

```
       <div class="container">
        <div class="row">

       <img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri());?>/imag     
       /beard-czar-best.JPG" alt="ddd">

      </div>
```

Comment: Please take a look at the developer tools network tab, see what URL the browser is trying to load the image from and if that fails. Also, I can’t see how this has anything to do with Twitter Bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

From the above code I can guess that the spelling may be wrong of **imag** to be **image**::

```
<img src="<?php echo esc_url(get_template_directory_uri());?>/image     
       /beard-czar-best.JPG" alt="ddd">
```

Comment: imag is exactly Folder. Its not matter.